# Printer doesn't lift Z between each probe

Tags: marlin, bed-leveling

I don't remember making a change to marlin but today when I tried to probe my bed my Z probe homed and slowly went downwards until the probe detected the first point. then without lifting it it just kept moving over the other points without lifting or even moving the z.

I canceled that and ran an `M48`, here's the output:

```
Recv: 1 of 5: z: -0.497
Recv: 2 of 5: z: -0.497
Recv: 3 of 5: z: -0.497
Recv: 4 of 5: z: -0.497
Recv: 5 of 5: z: -0.497
Recv: Finished!
Recv: Mean: -0.497500 Min: -0.497 Max: -0.497 Range: 0.000
Recv: Standard Deviation: 0.000000
Recv: 
Recv: X:74.00 Y:191.00 Z:5.29 E:0.00 Count X:5920 Y:15280 Z:116
Recv: ok
Recv: echo:endstops hit:  Z:0.29
```

Any ideas on what's going on?

[This is a link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/03ubktpsevbj4tx/AACOXEYqhIkrY3L7RiwSmV7Qa?dl=0) to my config files in a Dropbox folder.

I have an Anycubic i3 Mega-S with a graphical LCD screen.

Answer (score 1):

In my Pins.h folder turns out I needed to put a x-max pin. I hadn't defined that so it was randomly reading it as high. my printer thinking it can't go higher was freaking out basically :) this explains the other strange behavior i was experiencing!